# Changing the height of table view ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there any way to change the height of table view according the size of array?I am using table view as a drop down so i need to change the height of table view according the number of elements in array.

Answer (score 0):

First get the row height from the storyboard and create outlet of the tableView height 
then use the code as follow

as if row height is 50

```
(Swift code )
    let arrayCount = yourArray.count
    let tableHeight = arrayCount * 50

    tableHeightConstraint.constant = tableHeight
```

this will calculate the count of your tableView array and assign the same height to your tableView

Comment: height will be different for devices of different size,how can i hard code that in my code

Comment: are you using changing the row height programmatically for each row and device or is that fix while you have created the view ????

Comment: it is fixed but what i think is that the height of row will change according to the size of device

Comment: no according to the device the height remains the same but if you want to calculate the row height use the delegate method "heightForRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: calculate the height of each row and then add the height of every row to your table view height

Comment: where should i call this method :(

Comment: in your via controller where you have assign the  tableViewDelegate and when you are calling the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and other tableViewMethods

Comment: first try it using hardcode height and run it on simulator on different  devices and give it a try i will surely work if it won't then tell m

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the height of each row,and then

`height = rowHeight*array.count;
tableview.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);`

if you use autolayout,add a constrant like

`[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:height];`

Comment: but how to get the height of row

Comment: It depends on what you put in the cell,if you put label,you could caculate the size with the method [string sizeWithAttributes:attributeDic]